# Google Sheets: by the last non-empty cell in column, return the value in corresponding cell in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Hello!
 So I have dates in Column A (A3:A). And I have transactions (formatted as currency) in Column C (C3:C). So I want a cell D3 in Column D to show the date (preferably only month but it is not vital) of the last transaction.
 In other words I need a formula that would check the whole Column C, find the last transaction (assuming that there will be blank cells in that column), find the corresponding date in Column A (date when transaction occured) and return that value (date) in cell D3 of Column D.

 INDEX? MATCH? HLOOKUP?
 Please advise.

```
Column A          Column C          Column D
```

3   01/01/2021                   10.98                                   01/05/2021
4   01/02/2021                   15.64
5   01/03/2021
6   01/04/2021
7   01/05/2021                   20.93
8   01/05/2021                   76.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=+sort(A:A, row(A:A)*(C:C<>""),)
```

or

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(2, IF(C:C<>"", 1), 1))
```

or even

```
=lookup(9^9, C:C, A:A)
```

and see if that works?

Comment: They both work perfectly! Thanks! Though, if you don't mind, I'd like to know how they work. What does +sort function do? This is the first time I ever see it.

Comment: Which one would you recommend to stick to?

Comment: The + limits the output to a single row: so the range is sorted and only the first value of the sorted range is returned. My favorites ? The first and the third formula. ;-)